# FedEx 1.9 not working

Tags: shipping, fedex, magento-1.9

I've scoured the boards but can't find the specific answer.

Fedex Shipping is not working (new install) in 1.9.  The release notes indicated to do the following (below). Did that, but no luck.  Any suggestions.  We need this to work - Yesterday!!!

FedEx changed their endpoints for sandbox and production to the following:
Production: https://ws.fedex.com/web-services
Sandbox: https://wsbeta.fedex.com/web-services
Because of these changes, Magento cannot retrieve shipping rate information or print shipping labels for FedEx unless this fix is applied.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or error of any sort? I would add a few details about what isn't working, and paste an exception with stack trace if you see one.

Comment: No errors, it does not appear on the checkout page at all.  We are in sandbox mode, enabled and all methods allowed, debugging is on and I even have show method if not applicable selected.  We found the shipping_fedex.log - can't seem to figure out what it is telling us - here is a snippet

Comment: [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
            [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Severity] => ERROR
                    [Source] => prof
                    [Code] => 1000
                    [Message] => Authentication Failed
                )

            [Version] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

Comment: Looks like a FedEx login error, possibly. Have you called the FedEx web services team to verify your credentials? You do need an advanced web services account to perform some tasks, but I don't have all the details on that.

Comment: Is it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error Authentication Failed is always because you have invalid credentials.

Go check these, also try changing to sandbox mode. If still failing suggest get the FedEx request/response and raise a call with FedEx, they are pretty good.